# TableView overlaps the status bar in sliding view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ecslidingviewcontroller

I'm creating a slidingView controller using [ECSlidingViewController](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40118779/Slid...) like the one the previous version of Facebook had. Everything works fine but the menuViewController (tableViewController) is being overlapped by the status bar when I add an image to cell like shown below. [image] Does anyone know how to fix it.

Comment: try this one : self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdgeNone;

Comment: I recommend using @DhavalBhadania's approach if you're using ECSlidingViewController 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's works 100%

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
    {

        if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0")) {
            [self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, self.tableView.contentInset.left, self.tableView.contentInset.bottom, self.tableView.contentInset.right)];
        }
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Initialize table data

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to set tableview frame

```
[self.tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.tableView.frame.origin.x, 20, self.tableView.frame.size.width,self.tableView.frame.size.width)];
```